# Select Distinc on cakephp 3 return wrong fields

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

this function should return the field of the table I want, but this doesn't happen, return all field of the table, with simply sql work fine `"SELECT DISTINCT especie FROM packages"`

```
 public function listSpicies()
 {
    $packages = $this->Packages->find('all')
        ->select('especie')
        ->distinct('especie');
    $this->set([
        'success' => true,
        'data' => $packages,
        '_serialize' => ['success', 'data']
    ]);
 }
```

Comment: What does the generated SQL look like (check **[DebugKit](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html)**)? Where/how do you check what is being returned?

Answer (score 1):

I think You can use something like this:

```
$packages = $this->Packages->find('all' , [
            'fields' => [
                'anyAlias' => 'DISTINCT(espiece)' 
            ]
        ])
    ->toArray();
```

Notice. If this collection is serialized and outputted as a JSON, check `\App\Model\Entity\Package` - if `espiece` is inside `$_hidden` array - remove this from array